# Add labels to calculated cross product matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, cross-product

I have a table that I have created as follows

```
A_ID<-c(111,116,111,112,112,114,116,113,114,111,114,116,115,116,116)
U_ID<-c(221,221,222,222,223,223,223,224,224,225,225,225,226,226,226)

df_u_a<-data.frame(U_ID,A_ID)

myTab <- table(df_u_a) # count
myTab[] <- as.integer(as.logical(myTab)) # binary map
```

And a subsequent cross product matrix I've created as follows

```
CProd.Matrix <- crossprod(myTab[] %*% diag(1 / sqrt(colSums(myTab[]^2))))
```

This produced the following outputs

```
> myTab[]
     A_ID
U_ID  111 112 113 114 115 116
  221   1   0   0   0   0   1
  222   1   1   0   0   0   0
  223   0   1   0   1   0   1
  224   0   0   1   1   0   0
  225   1   0   0   1   0   1
  226   0   0   0   0   1   1
> CProd.Matrix
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.4082483 0.0000000 0.3333333  0.0 0.5773503
[2,] 0.4082483 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.4082483  0.0 0.3535534
[3,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.5773503  0.0 0.0000000
[4,] 0.3333333 0.4082483 0.5773503 1.0000000  0.0 0.5773503
[5,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000  1.0 0.5000000
[6,] 0.5773503 0.3535534 0.0000000 0.5773503  0.5 1.0000000
```

I don't know how to link the headers of the myTab[] to CProd.Matrix. For example like:

```
          111       112       113       114  115       116
111 1.0000000 0.4082483 0.0000000 0.3333333  0.0 0.5773503
112 0.4082483 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.4082483  0.0 0.3535534
113 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.5773503  0.0 0.0000000
114 0.3333333 0.4082483 0.5773503 1.0000000  0.0 0.5773503
115 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000  1.0 0.5000000
116 0.5773503 0.3535534 0.0000000 0.5773503  0.5 1.0000000
```

What I want to achieve is

1- to be able to query for a specific number like 111 and get the values. At the moment I can only manage to query for a row/column, like as below (but I can not manage to query for 111 for example)

```
> CProd.Matrix [1,]
[1] 1.0000000 0.4082483 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.5773503
```

2- see the corresponding headers for a each number like

```
          111       112       113       114  115       116
111 1.0000000 0.4082483 0.0000000 0.3333333  0.0 0.5773503
```

3- sort the values like

```
          111       116       112       114       113  115
111 1.0000000 0.5773503 0.4082483 0.3333333 0.0000000  0.0
```

Any ideas on how to achieve any of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dimnames` to assign the rownames and columnames.  In this case, there is only `colnames` of 'myTab' is needed as `dimnames`

```
dimnames(CProd.Matrix) <-rep(list(colnames(myTab)), 2)
CProd.Matrix
#          111       112       113       114 115       116
#111 1.0000000 0.4082483 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0 0.5773503
#112 0.4082483 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.4082483 0.0 0.3535534
#113 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.5773503 0.0 0.0000000
#114 0.3333333 0.4082483 0.5773503 1.0000000 0.0 0.5773503
#115 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0 0.5000000
#116 0.5773503 0.3535534 0.0000000 0.5773503 0.5 1.0000000
```

Now, based on the rownames, it can be subsetted

```
CProd.Matrix ["111",, drop = FALSE]
#    111       112 113       114 115       116
#111   1 0.4082483   0 0.3333333   0 0.5773503
```

sort the values after subsetting ?

```
t(apply(CProd.Matrix ["111",, drop = FALSE], 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE))
#    111       116       112       114 113 115
#111   1 0.5773503 0.4082483 0.3333333   0   0
```